# Tabulator Print the clicked row - Print PDF?

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I am looking if there is any I can add a print button to tabulator row and when it is clicked it prints that particular row?

http://tabulator.info/docs/4.3/print

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in functionality for this, but you could easily put something together to achieve this. This examples assumes that each row has a unique id field.

You could use a custom formatter to create a [Button Column](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.5/format#icon), then use that to filter the table to just that row, then print the table, then clear the filter:

```
//custom formatter definition
var printIcon = function(cell, formatterParams, onRendered){ //plain text value
    return "<i class='fa fa-print'></i>";
};

//column definition in the columns array
{formatter:printIcon, width:40, align:"center", cellClick:function(e, cell){ 

    //filter table to just this row
    table.Filter(function(data){
        return data.id == cell.getData().id;
    });

    //print the table
    table.print();

    //clear the filter
    table.clearFilter();
}},
```